# first-order and higher-order formula, how to distinguish them?

Tags: logic

I see logic formulas, which has quantifiers and other logical symbols. but one thing I find bit confusing, I want to know better.
while quantifier appears in both first-order and higher-order formulas, 
how can I tell which is first-order formula or higher-order formulas, if the type info is not provided? they looks same to me always.
is distinguishing them only based on type information ? or I am losing something?

In short, please explain me these two with examples.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are talking about first-order and higher-order predicate logic. They can be distinguished based on what they quantify over. In first order predicate logic the domain of quantification is individuals i.e. objects. A prototypical first-order formula would look like this:

```
 ∀(x): T(x)
```

where `x` e.g. ranges over the natural numbers. In second-order logic we are not just allowed to quantify over individuals. Now, we can also quantify into predicate position:

```
 ∀(P)∀(x): P(x) v ¬P(x)
```

To make the distinction in words. Let `x` range over the natural numbers and let `T` be the property of being divisible by 2. Then the first formula reads: "All natural numbers that are divisible by 2". Note that `T` is a constant here.

Now in the second formula let `x` range over the natural numbers and `P` over subsets of natural numbers. Then the second formula reads: "For all properties either the number has it or it does not have it."

In even higher-order logics your are not just allowed to quantify into predicate position you are also allowed to quantify over predicates. This means you can quantify over sets of sets not just over sets of individuals as in second-order logic.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now. so, if quantified variables accepts some arguments in formulas, that means it is higher-order. otherwise it is first-order. :)